# Ruby inside CoffeeScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

posts.js.coffee.erb

```
$('.list').infinitescroll {url: '<%= list_posts_path %>', triggerAt: 700, container: $('.container'), appendTo: $('.container'), page: 1}
```

This makes an exception:

> throw Error("NameError: undefined local variable or method
>   `list_posts_path' for #<#:0x00000003557438>\n ...

**list_posts_path** returns correct path if I use it in controller. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, don't do that. :)

You're not inside a controller, even though you're using ERB.  The coffeescript compiler doesn't know anything about your routes or routing helpers, which your views typically get access to through the controller.

Comment: Is there a way how to get that path in to js?

Comment: @Jonas The best way to make server-side data available to the JS is to put a `<script>` tag into your page (via the view or a layout) that provides *just* that data. (Or, if the data doesn't need to be available on page load, use Ajax.) That way, all your other JS can be concatenated, minified, and cached.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, and as mentioned early, you could do something like:

**your_layout.html.erb**

`<%= render partial: 'your_partial.html.erb', locals: { action_url: list_posts_path } %>`

**_your_partial.html.erb**

`<div id='container' data-action-url="<%= action_url %>" .... >`

**posts.js.coffee.erb**

`jQuery ->
    url = $('#container').data('action-url')
    console.log "loading url: #{url} !!!"`

Answer (score 3):

another alternative is to set a data attribute holding your path on some relevant element... then grab it with the js/coffee code

Answer (score 2):

include

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers } %>
```

at the beginning of the coffeescript file and then you will be able to access routes